# Quickstart Flask application failing for some reason

Tags: python, flask, pip

I created a fresh `virtualenv` environment for a Flask application called `flask-test` so that I could do some testing. Imagine my surprise when, running the quickstart application, I get the following error:

```
Honorss-MacBook-Air-2:Desktop Honors$ cd flask-testing
Honorss-MacBook-Air-2:flask-testing Honors$ source bin/activate
(flask-testing)Honorss-MacBook-Air-2:flask-testing Honors$ python app.py
* Restarting with stat
* Debugger is active!
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
app.run()
File "/Users/Honors/Desktop/flask-testing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 772, in run
run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
File "/Users/Honors/Desktop/flask-testing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/serving.py", line 633, in run_simple
application = DebuggedApplication(application, use_evalex)
File "/Users/Honors/Desktop/flask-testing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 169, in __init__
if self.pin is None:
File "/Users/Honors/Desktop/flask-testing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 179, in _get_pin
self._pin, self._pin_cookie = get_pin_and_cookie_name(self.app)
File "/Users/Honors/Desktop/flask-testing/lib/python3.5/site-packages/werkzeug/debug/__init__.py", line 96, in get_pin_and_cookie_name
h.update('cookiesalt')
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

The contents of `app.py` are:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World!'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True
    app.run()
```

`pip list` says that the contents of the environment are:

```
Flask (0.10.1)
Flask-Login (0.3.2)
Flask-WTF (0.12)
itsdangerous (0.24)
Jinja2 (2.8)
MarkupSafe (0.23)
pip (7.1.2)
setuptools (18.2)
Werkzeug (0.11)
wheel (0.24.0)
WTForms (2.0.2)
```

All of my other virtual environments run as expected.

Comment: That works for me. But maybe you need `return 'Hello World!'.encode('utf8')`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Seems like a bug: the related issue [Werkzeug 0.11 with Flask 0.10.1 and 'app.debug = True' won't start. #798](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/werkzeug/issues/798)

I create a new virtual environment using python3.5 and meet the same error, but if I don't use the debug mode, it's fine.

And as the issue says, downgrade Werkzeug to 0.10.4 seem works. You can have a try.

Comment: This bug is confirmed and should be fixed in Werkzeug 0.11.1