# Traceback when running simple Flask application

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edit: This question apparently has an answer here

[Quickstart Flask application failing for some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602708/quickstart-flask-application-failing-for-some-reason)

As well as a (closed and apparently fixed) GitHub issue here:

https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/issues/798

Unfortunately I'm still experiencing the problem, even with Werkzeug 0.12-dev (the latest code from GitHub).

I've just started developing a simple Flask application with Python 3.4 on Windows.  Literally, at the moment, here are the only contents of fileserve.py.

```
import os.path

from flask import abort, Flask


base_directory = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile(os.path.join(base_directory, 'fileserve.cfg'))


@app.route('/')
def index():
    abort(403)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

When I try running the application, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "fileserve.py", line 22, in <module>
    app.run(debug=True)
  File "C:\Users\jscholes\dev\fileserve\env\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 772, in run
    run_simple(host, port, self, **options)
  File "C:\Users\jscholes\dev\fileserve\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 633, in run_simple
    application = DebuggedApplication(application, use_evalex)
  File "C:\Users\jscholes\dev\fileserve\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\__init__.py", line 249, in __init__
    if self.pin is None:
  File "C:\Users\jscholes\dev\fileserve\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\__init__.py", line 259, in _get_pin
    self._pin, self._pin_cookie = get_pin_and_cookie_name(self.app)
  File "C:\Users\jscholes\dev\fileserve\env\lib\site-packages\werkzeug\debug\__init__.py", line 169, in get_pin_and_cookie_name
    h.update('cookiesalt')
TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing
```

This error occurs even with a simple "hello world" app:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'Hello world'
app.run(debug=True)
```

Is Flask's support for Python 3 just not very good?  Is there a workaround for this?  Working without the option of debug mode is not a great prospect.

Comment: What are the contents of the config file? I would like to test it

Comment: Quoting from a comment on the dup: "This bug is confirmed and should be fixed in Werkzeug 0.11.1 ."

Comment: Thanks, but I have the latest development code from GitHub (0.12-dev).

Comment: Can you confirm 1) your stacktrace still says `h.update('cookiesalt')`, and your werkzeug/debug/__init__.py, line 169 says, `h.update(b'cookiesalt')`. Note the missing "b", and 2) "print(werkzeug.__version__)" says "0.12-dev"?

Comment: I suspect that you are not using 0.12-dev, even if it have it and installed it.

Comment: I have just imported werkzeug and checked the value of werkzeug.__version__.  It says "0.12-dev".

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade your werkzeug installation.

In my install, with `werkzeug.__version__ == 0.11.7`, line 169 reads:

```
h.update(b'cookiesalt')
```

Comment: I have the latest code from GitHub (0.12-dev).